# Error: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

In this query:

```
update public.dctable
set dc = 1 
from (
        select d.*,
         min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as mintime,
         row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by 
time) as seqnum
  from public.dctable d
  ) dclk
  where dclk.seqnum <> 1
```

I get the error:

> ERROR: XX000: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate

Can't see what I'm missing. Just need to set dc=1 where time>mintime and seqnum<>1.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to join your source table to the from table like this

```
update public.dctable as s
set dc = 1 
from (
        select d.*,
         min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as mintime,
         row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by 
time) as seqnum
  from public.dctable d
  ) dclk
  where dclk.seqnum <> 1 AND s.id=dclk.id
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that Redshift follows Postgres semantics on the `update`.  If so:

```
update public.dctable d
    set dc = 1 
    from (select d.*,
                 min(time) over (partition by prod, customer, city, num) as mintime,
                 row_number() over (partition by prod, customer, city, num order by 
    time) as seqnum
          from public.dctable d
          ) d2
    where d2.prod = d.prod and d2.customer = d.customer and d2.city = d.city and
          d2.num = d.num and d2.mintime < d.time;
```

I don't think the `row_number()` is necessary for what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because the main table to be updated doesn't isn't directly joined to the tables in the `using` part of the query. the where clause must have the updated table as part of a predicate. e.g. (making your query work as is) :

```
update public.dctable set dc = 1 
  from (
    select by prod, customer, city, num, min(time) as time
    from public.dctable group by 1,2,3,4
  ) dclk
where dclk.prod = dctable.prod
and dclk.customer =dctable.customer
and dclk.city=dctable.city
and dclk.num=dctable.num
and dclk.time=dctable.time
```