# Two similar UPDATE statements in Redshift, one throws an error but the other doesn't

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have been working on converting some SQL scripts from T-SQL to Redshift and came across this error a few times: `Error: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate` wit UPDATE statements using JOINs.

There are several questions on SO about this problem and I was able to use them to fix my UPDATE statements by using subqueries. ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41368086/update-statement-error-target-table-must-be-part-of-an-equijoin-predicate) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50819372/error-target-table-must-be-part-of-an-equijoin-predicate) specifically)

I thought I had this all figured out until just now when I was able to execute an UPDATE statement similar to the ones I was getting errors for without issue. I want to understand what is going on here so I can be better at writing queries for Redshift.

Here is an example of one of the UPDATE statements that threw the above error:

```sql
UPDATE billing_temp
SET spotlink = sl.spotlink
FROM billing_temp AS bt
LEFT JOIN spot_link AS sl
    ON bt.dupeid = sl.dupeid;
```

And here is the UPDATE statement that is working without any changes:

```sql
UPDATE public.billingcombined
SET revenue_type = r.revenue_type
FROM public.billingcombined AS b
JOIN public.revenuetype AS r
    ON b.contract_number = r.contract_number;
```

These look exactly the same to me. The only difference I can see is that the first one is using two temporary tables, but I wouldn't think this would cause an issue.

**EDIT:** I just saw the LEFT JOIN in the first query vs the JOIN in the second. Is this the reason the second query works?

**EDIT2:** After trying another UPDATE statement with a JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN I was able to confirm that using a JOIN allows it to run without error.

For reference, here is how I had to correct the first query to run without errors based on what I learned from the linked SO questions:

```sql
UPDATE billing_temp
SET spotlink = btsl.spotlink
FROM
(
    SELECT bt.dupeid,
           sl.spotlink
    FROM billing_temp AS bt
    LEFT JOIN spot_link AS sl
        ON bt.dupeid = sl.dupeid
) AS btsl
WHERE billing_temp.dupeid = btsl.dupeid;
```

The answers say the problem is you can't use the table getting updated directly in the FROM clause. But now that doesn't seem to be the case for my second UPDATE statement.

Comment: As my edit #2 shows the difference that is causing the second UPDATE statement to not throw an error is the fact that it is using a JOIN rather than a LEFT JOIN. I am going to ask a separate question about why this is the case.

Comment: The error message is basically saying you can’t use a LEFT/OUTER JOIN in an update statement: https://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html. Presumably you discovered this when you were fixing your original updates statements using subqueries - so I’m a bit confused why you are subsequently wondering why an update with a LEFT JOIN is giving an error?