# What is the difference between a JOIN and LEFT JOIN when running an UPDATE in Redshift?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

This question is stemming from another question I asked here: [Two similar UPDATE statements in Redshift, one throws an error but the other doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75086327/two-similar-update-statements-in-redshift-one-throws-an-error-but-the-other-doe)

This is not asking about the difference between a JOIN and a LEFT JOIN, I understand that.

Rather I am specifically asking about how Redshift works when running an UPDATE statement similar to this one:

```sql
UPDATE billing_temp
SET spotlink = sl.spotlink
FROM billing_temp AS bt
LEFT JOIN spot_link AS sl
    ON bt.dupeid = sl.dupeid;
```

Which throws this error:
`Error: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate`

And how it differs from running an UPDATE statement like this:

```sql
UPDATE public.billingcombined
SET revenue_type = r.revenue_type
FROM public.billingcombined AS b
JOIN public.revenuetype AS r
    ON b.contract_number = r.contract_number;
```

Which does not throw the error.

I can see that the bad statement contains a LEFT JOIN while the good one uses a regular JOIN.

I want to understand what an equijoin predicate means in this situation and why the LEFT JOIN does not work.

Answer (score 1):

*Amazon Redshift SQL* does not support `Left`, `right`, and `full outer` joins in the `FROM` clause of an `UPDATE` statement; they return this error:

```
ERROR: Target table must be part of an equijoin predicate
```

Reference:

- [Amazon Redshift - Update](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UPDATE.html)
- [Amazon Redshift - Update Examples](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_Examples_of_UPDATE_statements.html)